# symfony 3 : i want to create a slider that filter research list betwenn min val and max val

Tags: javascript, ajax, symfony

this is the view that let show range slider and the list of hotels
i want to filter research by clicking on the range

```
{% block body %}
<div class="container" style="width:800px;">

    <div align="center">
        <input type="range" min="10000" max="55000" step="1000" value="10000" id="min_price" name="min_price" />
        <span id="price_range"></span>
    </div>
    <br /><br /><br />
    <div id="product_loading">
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="row">
                {% for x in Hotels %}
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="{{ asset('uploads/brochures/'~x.brochure) }}" alt="">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h4 class="pull-right">{{ x.price }}</h4>
                                <h4><a href="#">{{ x.titre }}</a>
                                </h4>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#min_price').change(function(){
            var price = $(this).val();
            $("#price_range").text("Product under Price Rs." + price);
            $.ajax({
                url:" {{ path('Hotel__') }},
                data:'price' +price ,
                method:"POST",
                success:function(data){
                    $("#product_loading").fadeIn(500).html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

My problem is in AJAX ! i must specify URL and DATA Any suggestion ?
i must put on the url the view who let me to filter resut and in Date the parameters
 so i do  getListHotelInfBudget in Repository

```
public function getListHotelInfBudget($budget)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('h');
    $qb->select('h')
        ->where('h.price <= :budget')
        ->setParameter('budget', $budget);
    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

controller

```
public function getListAction($budget)
{
    $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('.............');
    $list =$em->getListHotelInfBudget($budget);
    return $this->render('....Bundle:....:listHotel.html.twig',array('list'=>$list));
}
```

and the routing configuration :

```
Hotel__:
path:     /hotel/{budget}
defaults: { _controller: .......Bundle:.....:getList }
```

but an exception
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Some mandatory parameters are missing ("price") to generate a URL for route

Comment: Do you get a value for $budget in the getListAction or it's empty?

Comment: No it 's empty it should take value from sliders ! but in the URL i must put the vue who filter the research that 's why i do a function getListHotelInfBudget and i must call it in  URL zone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to be very badly organized.
How do you want to pass the price to the getListAction ?

With budget as GET parameter ? Or with price as POST parameter ?

Here your error comes because :

Your **Hotel__** route needs `{budget}` to be generated.

In your template you call `{{ path('Hotel__') }}`.

So you have to define a budget :

```
{{ path('Hotel__',{'budget':142}) }}
```

But I don't think it makes sence, because your budget probably must come from the sliders and not from twig.

---

**EDIT :**

You can pass the price with `data: {price : price }`

And get it in your controller like this :

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

...

public function getListAction(Request $request)
{
    $price = $request->get('price');
}
```

Then, remove all {budget} occurences .

Comment: so what should i put in URL !

Comment: this is the first time that i post on stackoverflow and i 'm please to find an answer for my question and I don't know how to accept your answer :/ tell me how and i will do it :D

Comment: By the answer on the top left under the answer score, a V button ;)